# Django crate custom reusable app that include some changes on manage.py

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I'm following [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/reusable-apps/) documentation to create a reausable Django application, but the main implementation is on *manage.py* e.g:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

from foo import bar  #Need to append this import

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'educat_erp.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc

    is_testing = 'test' in sys.argv    ## This lines 
    if is_testing:                     ## needs to append
       bar()                           ## when add the aplication

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Theres any way to create a reusable package that only need to be added on INSTALLED_APPS and modify the manage.py or any other way to check if tests are running to change some test configurations before run.

Comment: How about you fix your tests to run without these lines? And BTW your lines imply that there is no other command line argument ever being "test".

Comment: Your assumption that tests will be always executed via `manage.py` is wrong. If someone will be using [pytest](https://pytest.org) (everyone in my bubble does), then you're out of luck. Dont monkeypatch `manage.py`, fix your tests instead.

Comment: The idea is implement some changes on config while test is running to speedup the Django Test like. ` if is_testing:  logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)`  following this article https://brobin.me/blog/2016/08/7-ways-to-speed-up-your-django-test-suite/ @yedpodtrzitko @klaus-d

Comment: Yeah... dont do it that way. Create a custom settings file with all the modifications you need there, and pass it to manage.py: `/manage.py test --settings=sasalele.settings.test_settings`